# Is it possible to change the name of a Survey?

Tags: survey, salesforce-survey

I created a survey with a nonspecific name, thinking I might be able to change it later. But now I find that I can only change the names of versions of the survey. Is there any way to change the actual name?

Answer (score 1):

Currently editing a Survey name is not allowed.

You can make a copy of the version which has all the details you need and create a brand new Survey and then you can name it to whatever you want.

There is an open idea -https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000UJWsQAO submitted to allow Survey name change later, please go ahead and upvote it to get it prioritized.